# Why does Java permit interfaces to have static readonly fields while .NET interfaces cannot?

Tags: java, .net, language-design

I faced with a sample code in Java and it brought me a question.

**Java** sample code is:

```
...
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "msvcrt" : "c"), CLibrary.class);
    void printf(String format, Object... args);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CLibrary.INSTANCE.printf("Hello, World\n");
}
```

But in **C#** we cannot write like that:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    static readonly int staticInt = 5;                          // compile error
    static readonly SomeClass staticInstance = new SomeClass(); // compile error
}
```

What is the difference between these two languages/frameworks?

What design policy permit java to have const fields in an interface or what prevents .NET from having that?

Comment: It was a design mistake in Java which they decided not to make in C# ... ;)

Comment: The general answer: C# was not created by following the same logic as the designers of Java. It's a different language that has many overlapping goals and hence a lot of overlapping style and features. But also a lot of differences.

Comment: Because C# is an amazing copy of Java (there aren't probably two languages closer to each other than C# and Java), but made years after Java and because they didn't copy every single feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of interfaces to hold constants is usually frowned on these days in Java too. (I'd say that storing *non-compile-time-constant* fields like your example is even more frowned upon.)

Fundamentally, it's at odd with the idea of an interface: a contract that the implementation will uphold. The implementation isn't going to provide the field, so what's it doing there?

I suspect the C# team decided that it was sufficiently at odds with the concept behind interfaces to not include it in the language. I don't know whether it's just a C# restriction or a CLR restriction too. For example, I know that the CLR allows interfaces to declare nested types, but C# doesn't currently allow this.

Comment: I agree with you. interfaces are contracts. there are alternatives to interface constants like enums, singleton pattern, static utility classes like java.lang.Math class

Comment: Also: The introduction of the `enum` feature made compile time constants in interfaces even more unnecessary: you can replace them with type-safe, compile-time-checked, rich `enum` values now.

Answer (score 2):

[In C#:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

> Interfaces consist of methods,
>   properties, events, indexers, or any
>   combination of those four member
>   types. An interface cannot contain
>   constants, fields, operators, instance
>   constructors, destructors, or types.
>   It cannot contain static members.
>   Interfaces members are automatically
>   public, and they cannot include any
>   access modifiers.

[In Java:](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html)

> Every field declaration in the body of
>   an interface is implicitly public,
>   static, and final.
>
> Every field in the body of an
>   interface must have an initialization
>   expression, which need not be a
>   constant expression. The variable
>   initializer is evaluated and the
>   assignment performed exactly once,
>   when the interface is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all fields in an interface are implicitly static and final. 
But its considered bad practice. To qoute Joshua Bloch from Effective Java:

> The constant interface pattern is a
>   poor use of interfaces. That a class
>   uses some constants internally is an
>   implementation detail. Implementing a
>   constant interface causes this
>   implementation detail to leak into the
>   class's exported API. It is of no
>   consequence to the users of a class
>   that the class implements a constant
>   interface. In fact, it may even
>   confuse them. Worse, it represents a
>   commitment: if in a future release the
>   class is modified so that it no longer
>   needs to use the constants, it still
>   must implement the interface to ensure
>   binary compatibility. If a nonfinal
>   class implements a constant interface,
>   all of its subclasses will have their
>   namespaces polluted by the constants
>   in the interface.

As to why it is considered bad practice, I think a class implementing an interface with constant fields is exposing  these in  the interface to outside code which consumes this class which in most cases is not what is required.

Comment: That's a specific usage pattern. It does not apply in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's weird that Java chose to allow this.

An interface is a contract for a Role. That is, it's an spec that all objects must implement in order to be considered as suitable/swappable candidates for that Role. It should contain *the messages/methods that the Role responds to and the notifications that it triggers for interested listeners*.

Fields are an implementation detail (and your example contains actual implementation dictating the return value for the INSTANCE field too) and do not belong within the contract. If you wanted to map this to C#, you should probably move it to an **abstract base class**, which allows default implementation to be specified in addition to specifying some members that derived classes must also implement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess COM's Microsoft Interface Description Language does not allow it. So it's just an adaptation for the Windows environment, much like prefixing interface names with `I`.

Comment: Maybe.
.net inherits some things from windows ,com and C++. const, enum, non-nested static class, delegate (function pointer)
this may be too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Like most questions of this form, the question is basically pointless. It's not like the designers of Java and C# had a meeting about it. Historically Java came first so you would really have to ask the designers of C#, not that the question would necessarily make sense to them either. It's just how they saw it at the time.